# Is it possible to store System.Decimal.MinValue and System.Decimal.MinValue in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, ado.net, decimal

Considering that the maximum size of a data type supported by SQLite is 8 bytes, can I store a Decimal.MinValue, Decimal.MaxValue in a NUMERIC column. I am using the [ADO.NET provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) for SQLite by phxsoftware. Does the driver internally store the value as a string and do the conversion both ways?

I do get a System.OverflowException while trying to retrieve the Decimal.MinValue/MaxValue.

Comment: I can see the following value stored in the table (via SQLite Database Browser)' -7.92281625142644e+28 ' .It seems to be stored as a string. Guess it's rounded it off to a higher value and hence while converting back to decimal from string, I get the OverflowException.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The [System.Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) type has a much wider range of values (-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 :: 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335) than the SQLite 8-byte INTEGER (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 :: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) and requires more precision than the SQLite REAL ([IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)) can provide.

From http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html:

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may
>   contain values using all five storage
>   classes. When text data is inserted
>   into a NUMERIC column, the storage
>   class of the text is converted to
>   INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference) if such conversion is
>   lossless and reversible. For
>   conversions between TEXT and REAL
>   storage classes, SQLite considers the
>   conversion to be lossless and
>   reversible if the first 15 significant
>   decimal digits of the number are
>   preserved. If the lossless conversion
>   of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not
>   possible then the value is stored
>   using the TEXT storage class. No
>   attempt is made to convert NULL or
>   BLOB values.
>
> A string might look like a
>   floating-point literal with a decimal
>   point and/or exponent notation but as
>   long as the value can be expressed as
>   an integer, the NUMERIC affinity will
>   convert it into an integer. Hence, the
>   string '3.0e+5' is stored in a column
>   with NUMERIC affinity as the integer
>   300000, not as the floating point
>   value 300000.0.

If you compare `-7.92281625142644e+28` to `-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335`, you'll see that the floating point value has been rounded down to a value (-79,228,162,514,264,400,000,000,000,000) that is outside the bounds of what System.Decimal can store.  Your ADO.NET provider is doing the best job it can, but because of the data conversions, it just won't work.  If you really need to store the full range of System.Decimal, then you're going to have to store it as a text, and resign yourself to not being able to operate on the value as a number within SQLite.

Comment: @Craig - I can see the following value stored in the table (via SQLite Database Browser)' -7.92281625142644e+28 ' It seems to be stored as a string. While reading back the value I was expecting the ADO.NET provider to rightly convert it to a decimal.